# Linear transformation problem from R^4 to R^2

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Lets look at T = R^4 -> R^2, Prove that T is a linear transformation.

where : T$
\begin{bmatrix} 
x \\
y  \\
z     \\
w
\end{bmatrix}= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
x + z \\
y + w 
\end{bmatrix}$

Proof : Let A and B be dummy vectors such as

$A=
\begin{bmatrix} 
a_1  \\
a_2  \\
a_3     \\
a_4
\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=
\begin{bmatrix} 
b_1   \\
b_2   \\
b_3     \\
b_4
\end{bmatrix}$

$$
T(cA + B) 
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
ca1 + ca3 +b1 +b3 \\
ca2 + ca4 +b2 +b4 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
ca1 + ca3 \\
ca2 + ca4 
\end{bmatrix} 
+
\begin{bmatrix} 
b1 + b3 \\
b2 + b4 
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
c 
\begin{bmatrix} 
a1 + a3 \\
a2 + a4 
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix} 
b1 + b3 \\
b2 + b4 
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
cT(A)+T(B)
$$

Also, 
$$
T
\begin{bmatrix} 
0   \\
0   \\
0     \\
0
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so T is an empty vector Is this a sufficient proof?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to show is that $T$ satisfies $T(cA+B) =cT(A) +T(B)$ for any vectors $A,B$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and any scalar from the field, and $T(0) =0$. It looks like you got it. That should be sufficient proof.